# PHP WebService not working when invoked from Java or .Net

Tags: java, php, web-services, parsing

We have created a PHP Soap web service and works perfectly when called from a PHP client.
But when we try to call it from Java it seems to return null.
We have used SoapUI and everything seems to be alright...
Used Wireshark to catch the data sent to the client and the data seems alright.

We tried changing the namespace and it throws an exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unexpected response element {http://[URLhere]//ws/sWSDL.php}getServiceXMLDetailsResponse expected: {subscriptionWS}getServiceXMLDetailsResponse
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$RpcLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:603)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy21.getServiceXMLDetails(Unknown Source)
    at reynardito.ReyNardito.main(ReyNardito.java:28)
```

And using Wireshark the data packet contains the right information, so it seems to be a parsing error of some kind...

Anyone have solved this before?

Comment: Can you post the code for how you are invoking the webservice in php and in java? It would be better if we know how you are sending the request...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nusoap?

If so...change the url {http://[URLhere]//ws/sWSDL.php?wsdl} instead of {http://[URLhere]//ws/sWSDL.php}

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the WSDL.
It was missing some parts.